# web2py, microsoft sql server and restricted names for fields

Tags: sql-server, web2py

Is there any option to set the words "file", "key" and "trigger" as field names for ms-sql server?

We have pretty big application written with web2py with PostgreSQL as db, ans some of the fields has those names.  One customer wishes to use ms-sql as db server, And I'm trying not to break compatibility within the DB structure.

Using square brackets (found in google) didn't help (could not use '[file]') - the ms-sql rejected it.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) is pretty clear on this:

> Although it is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved
>   keywords as identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, you
>   can do this only by using delimited identifiers.

The delimiters used in SQL Server are either double quotes or `[]`.  So, you can define them as:

```
[file]
```

or

```
"file"
```

Note that you need to use the delimiters wherever they appear.

The use of reserved words for such columns is discouraged.  However, you might actually have a use case of compatibility between different databases where this capability will be useful.

I don't know why square bracket would fail.  It works on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea845/1).

Comment: tnx. I'm working with web2py.  It's look like feeding the name directly with [] working, but web2py can't use it with ms-sql, and the field name on the query gets the name with the [] (the query result has field names '[file]', this isn't compatible with the dictionary I'm excepting.  tnx anyway.

Comment: @GuyDafny . .  do the double quotes work?  These are used in more databases and might be supported better.

Comment: The double quotes didn't work.  It looks like problem with the web2py DAL.  tnx anyway, I'll modify the fields name in my application (and the hell with compitability ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled into this same issue when trying to use a legacy SQL Server table with fields that don't conform to identifier name rule, such as `'My File'`.

Reading the source code I found that a **`rname` field attribute** exists for these cases:

```
Field('my_file', 'string', rname='[My File]'),
```

With this, Web2Py works with the `my_file` field name, the actual SQL/DML generated to interact with the database will use `[My File]` instead.